# Differences between blob detection and image segmentation

Tags: image-processing, blob, image-segmentation

please can anyone explain the main differences respectively the relations between this techniques. On the one and in many tutorials image segmentation is used as the base od blob detection. But on the other hand blob detection algorithms like Connected-component labeling is equal to a Region-growing methods which is related to image segmentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have distinct concepts, however, sometimes they do overlap.

Let me try to explain it in layman's terms:

- **Blob detection** refers to a specific **application of image processing techniques**, whose purpose is to isolate (one or more) *objects* (aka. regions) in the input image;
- **Image segmentation** refers to a **classification of image processing techniques** used to partition an image into smaller segments (groups of pixels).

*Image segmentation* have many applications, and so it happens that one of them is actually **object detection**. This is where the confusion usually surfaces because now these 2 terms mean similars things:

> The application of image segmentation techniques for *object detection*, is exactly what blob detection is all about.

So I believe the main difference is: *image segmentation* refers to a vast **group of techniques**, and *blob detection* refers to an **application** of those techniques.